# how to passing the data to the other page in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass data from one page to another page. My GUI is like this:

First Page:

[image]

Second Page:

[image]

Third Page:

[image]

The issue here is that, when the user pressed the breakfast/lunch/dinner button, they will be going to the second page which displays all the restaurant lists. And when the users press the restaurant list, they will be able to see the menu list according to the categories above. But I am not capable of carrying the categories value selection to the next page which I need the keyword to sent to the database.

The categories navigation:

```
child: InkWell(onTap: (){
                  if(categoriesList[index].name == "Breakfast"){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new restaurantLISTVIEW()));
                    }
                  else if(categoriesList[index].name == "Lunch"){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new restaurantLISTVIEW()));
                  }
                  else if(categoriesList[index].name == "Dinner"){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new restaurantLISTVIEW()));
                  }
                },
```

The keyword needs to sent to the third page of selection categories which the code is:

```
  Future<List> getData() async{

var url = 'http://10.0.2.2/foodsystem/breakfastlist.php';
var data = {
  'product_type': 'breakfast',
  'product_owner': widget.list[widget.index]['restaurant_id'],
};
var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data));
//final response= await http.get("http://10.0.2.2/foodsystem/getdata.php");
return json.decode(response.body);}
```

I am not sure how to pass the categories value of breakfast/lunch/dinner from the first page to the third page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second page must receive the category by witch to fetch the corresponding restaurants list

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {

  String category;
  SecondPage({this.category});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SecondPageState();

  //...
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  List restaurants;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    restaurants = [];
  }

  void fetchRestaurants() {
    // fetch restaurants by category using widget.category
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Thus, your `InkWell` will look like this

```
InkWell(
  onTap: (){
    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=> new SecondPage(category: categoriesList[index].name)));
  },
)
```

Comment: thankyou for the information. It helps me finding the answer

Comment: You're welcome. If your question is answered, mark is as the correct answer

Comment: I am still having some stuck on passing the data to the third page, the error is the undefined name of "widget". I did update the question on the answer section below. Thank you

Comment: You second page is StatelessWidget ?

Comment: yes. this is the link I post for the detail about my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65556432/14889221

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. Basically, you would have to pass the category value to the second page, and from the second page to third page:

```
class CategoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute<void>(
            builder: (context) => RestaurantsPage(
              category: 'dinner',
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text('Dinner'),
    );
  }
}

class RestaurantsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String category;

  const RestaurantsPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.category,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute<void>(
            builder: (context) => MenuPage(
              category: 'dinner',
              restaurant: 'restaurantA',
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text('Restaurant A'),
    );
  }
}

class MenuPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String category;
  final String restaurant;

  const MenuPage({Key key, @required this.category, @required this.restaurant})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuPageState createState() => _MenuPageState();
}

class _MenuPageState extends State<MenuPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // Get menus using category and restaurant
    getMenus(category: widget.category, restaurant: widget.restaurant);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```